# UDP networking with multiple network

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp

I'm currently developing a network application on my machine with 2 network interfaces with the following setup -

[image: Current network setting]

I want to send UDP message by using the first configuration with IP `192.168.1.2`.

```
using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(5556))
{
    udpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 5556);
    // DO STUFF
}
```

When I try this I get the following error -

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it

Strange this is that when I disable my other network that this works perfectly but with 2 connections (LAN & WiFi) it doesn't work anymore...
I guess that it is sending on wrong adapter?
Is this because my Default gateway is the same or what am I doing wrong?
I'm new to developing network-based applications...

Comment: Incidentally you do not need to call Connect with UDP - all that does is every time you call send you do not need to pass the end point you want to send to.

Comment: Also you can use the loopback address: 127.0.0.1, and have interfaces connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify an `IPEndPoint` with networking card IP like this:

```
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), portNum);
UdpClient client = new UdpClient(endpoint);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling `UdpClient` which IP to use.

`UdpClient` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k227d11f.aspx) that can take an `IPEndPoint`.

```
const string ip = "192.168.1.2";
const int port = 5556;

var listenEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
var udpClient = new UdpClient(listenEndpoint);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that good in C# but I think I understand the problem. You are binding your udpClient to port 5556 but you're not specifying the IP address. The OS will select the IP address for you. I suppose it could be either 192.168.1.2 or 192.168.1.5, you cannot tell which one.
Then with the same udpClient you are trying to connect to a remote host listening on 192.168.1.2, port 5556. And probably nobody is listening there. This is why you receive the error.

I would do the following (sorry for my bad C# skills):

- Have two udpClient's, in one thread or program/process:

  ```
  var udpClient1 = new UdpClient("192.168.1.2", 5556);
  ```

This one will listen on IP addres 192.168.1.2, port 5556.

- in second thread or program/process:

  ```
  var udpClient2 = new UdpClient(); //doesn't matter which (IP, port) the OS will bind it to.
  udpClient2.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 5556); //connect to peer/server listening in (IP=192.168.1.2, port=5556)
  ```

You could handle both udpClient1 and udpClient2 in the same thread also.
The important is that if you connect to and (IP, port) there has to be some application/process listening there. Otherwise, the remote host will send an ICMP message indicating the datagram cannot be delivered. The connection is refused.